# How to make animated subtitles

Tags: avi, subtitles, mencoder

I have seen a few avi files where the subtitles are animated. How are these made? Can they be made with mencoder?

Comment: Animated in what way? Any example?

Comment: Like they might sparkle, light up, fall off or fall into place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use a program called aegisub to create .ass files, then use a program to hardcode the ass files into an avi file.